# How do I properly utilise `.reduce` to count the total number of characters in an array?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use reduce to perform a total character count of elements in an array, but I don't know how to go about writing the return properly.

This is my attempt.

```
function characterCount(array) {

  return array.reduce(function(array) {
    return array.reduce()

  })
}
```

This is the problem.

```
describe('characterCount', () => {

  it('should sum the total number of characters in the array', () => {
    expect(characterCount(['Stay', 'hungry', 'stay', 'foolish'])).to.equal(21)

    expect(characterCount(['Where', 'is', 'the', 'stone'])).to.equal(15)

    expect(characterCount(['Pack', 'it', 'up', 'pack', 'it', 'in', 'let', 'me', 'begin'])).to.equal(26)

  })
})
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you doing this for the sake of learning reduce? Otherwise I would not recommend this approach. You could maybe just do a `join('').length` on your array to achieve that.

Comment: @RenanSouza There's nothing wrong with using `reduce` for this job. It's much more efficient than your `join('')` approach

Comment: You'll want to to read [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) again and check which parameters the callback function takes. Hint: it's not an `array`.

Comment: @Bergi one would be readabillity, and even though performance difference is pretty insignificant among the two options, I dont think `reduce` then sum + length would be faster then `join`, both need to loop, `join` is simpler.

Comment: @RenanSouza What do you mean by "reduce *then* sum"? You should sum *during* the fold. And notice that `join` would need to allocate and fill a huge string, which is expensive.

Comment: @Bergi obviously, it's in my answer in fact. I mean you would sum during the reduce, which would result in several sums, one for each iteration.

Comment: @RenanSouza the difference is that `join` needs to create a (potentially large) string in memory first. `reduce()` just keeps track of a single number.

Comment: @MarkMeyer that is one valid argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function characterCount(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(charCount, item) {
    return charCount + item.length;
  }, 0); // 0 is the initial data. charCount starts at 0 on first pass
}

console.log(characterCount(['Stay', 'hungry', 'stay', 'foolish'])); // 21
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with reduce function:

```js
const a= ['Stay', 'hungry', 'stay', 'foolish'];
const result  = a.reduce((sum,ele) => sum + ele.length, 0);

console.log(result);
```

or with another solution like this:

```js
const a= ['Stay', 'hungry', 'stay', 'foolish'];
const result  = a.join('').length;

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use reduce to iterate over the array using a callback that receives the expected values as specified in [Array reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
function characterCount(array) {
  return array.reduce((currentSum, nextWord) => {
  currentSum += nextWord.length
  return currentSum
  }, 0)
}
    
var list = ['Stay', 'hungry', 'stay', 'foolish']
    
console.log(characterCount(list))
```